# varnish.log pushing 300G

Tags: ubuntu, logging, varnish

I inherited a server recently and saw that there is `varnish.log` file in `/var/log/varnish` that is currently pushing upwards of 300G file size. I looks to me like a feed of the data I get when I run `varnishlog`.

I can't seem to find where varnish is set to log in the first place. There is no reference in my `/etc/varnish/default.vcl` file.

In `/etc/default/varnish` my `varnishlog` file is all commented out, specifically:

```
# Uncomment this to enable logging for varnish.  Please make sure you have
# enough disk space for significant amounts of log data.  To disable logging,
# set the variable to "0", "no", or leave it unset.
```

Default setting seems to not enable logging, so I'm wondering where else it might be turned on?

Of not, it's actively being written to.  Running `tail -f on varnish.log` shows a flow of input.

Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: I would check in rsyslog and see if logging is configured there. Also, it might be a good idea to add an entry in /etc/logrotate.d that would rotate the logs on a daily or weekly basis (depending on foot traffic).

Comment: @ryekayo the out put is shown here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25333913/
it looks like it's rotated daily, or should be?  Is it possible to disable that logging from taking place? My configs point to it being turned off by default.

Comment: To add to that, logrotate looks like it's set to archive over 7 days, but there are no archived files in the directory. Just one huge varnish.log file.

Comment: Try this out: `sudo logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.d/varnish` That may give you a clue as to what is happening. I've had this issue happen to one of my problems before.. In my case, the daemon in charge of logging never sent a SIGUSR to the PID and it just kept appending to the same log file..

Comment: @ryekayo Interesting output... http://paste.ubuntu.com/25334071/
 I also did try renaming varnish.log to see if I could safely remove it, and interestingly it kept being written to, which seemed odd to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifiying your logrotate script

```
/var/log/varnish/*.log {
  daily
  rotate 7
  missingok
  size 50M
  compress
  delaycompress
  missingok
  postrotate
    if [ -d /run/systemd/system ]; then
       systemctl -q is-active varnishlog.service || exit 0
    fi
    /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d varnishlog reload > /dev/null
  endscript
}
```

I changed the /var/log/varnish/varnish.log to *.log so it addresses varnish.log and varnishnsca.log. I added size 50M to rotate the logs when it reaches 50M. At this point I would try to force the change with logrotate. Try using the -d flag first to see if the output changes at all. If it does say it can rotate in debug mode, try `logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/varnish`

Comment: I feel like I'm on the right track.  Running -d showed that an archive was ready to be created. Running -f created archives for both varnish.log and varnishncsa but now the original varnish.log file is gone. Remaining in the directory is a file called varnish.log.1 which is ~280G in size and is no longer being written to.  When I nano varnish.log it says root is using the file still, but it is no longer in the directory.

Comment: Awesome! That certainly solved the issue of it rotating.. Now its up to you if you wanna keep the file or tarball it up and going forward logrotate will compress your log files.